# How to Display Beeper/Alert/Popup window like Facebook in my SharePoint site?

Tags: web-part, popup

I am using SharePoint Foundation.

I have created 1 Custom List. And entry added directly into that List using my EventReceiver. And EventReceiver is created on my Document Library, which is called when any Document is Add/Update/Delete that entry added into my this CustomList.

Now I want to display Beeper/Alert/Popup in my sharepoint site like in Facebook when any entry added(inserted) into this CustomList.

How it should implement to display it (in bottom left corner of the page) when any of my page is open in my site ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using JavaScript, and the JavaScript Client Object Model in SharePoint. There is the Notifications API - which could show your alert - and you could use it to check your List. I'd then write JavaScript to poll the list for new items.

In terms of putting a reference to that JavaScript into each page, I would suggest a delegate control of some form, adding a JavaScript reference into the 'Additional Page Header' section of your page.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Can you please provide some code part (of JavaScript) ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use SP.UI.Notify.addNotification in Client Object Model, here is an example of different kinds of notifications:

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/pages/sharepoint-showing-notification-and-status-message-using-sp-js.aspx